# Rearrange existing options based boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, var

i would like to know is there a way to rearrange existing options based on boolean value ?

Example;

> If matchtime===true, option['time'] must have priority in the options list
> If matchquality===true, option['quality'] must also be priority in the options list

```
<form> 
    <select name="option_id" >
        <option disabled selected value> -- select a category -- </option>
        <optgroup label="Recommended">
        <option disabled > ---- </option>
        </optgroup> -->
        <optgroup label="All Category">
        <option id="time" value="time" >Time </option>
        <option id="quality" value="Quality" >Quality</option>
        <option id="management" value="management" >management</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select></form>
```

Javascript:

```
var sel=this.form.elements['option_id'];
var groups = sel.getElementById('optgroup');
groups=groups[0];
var opt=document.createElement('option');
opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("newoptions"));
var matchtime=true;
var matchquality = false;
if(matchtime===true){
   groups.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Extra:

I want to create an autosuggest category based on boolean value. If possible, i also want to label the options with the word "Recommended".

If not possible, i was thinking on arrange them using optgroup to separate options that its boolean value is true.

Reference link: https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/option/dom-demo.php

Comment: How are you rendering this and how are `matchtime` and `matchquality` set or changed? Show what code you have to manage the form if you can.

Comment: I add some more code but i dont think its going to help.